# Kotlin source files in "src/main/kotlin" can't resolve other gradle module classes

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I have a multimodule project with gradle that is working fine for a while now.
Now I started to refactor my old java code and used some kotlin classes for it.
Unfortunately I have a dependency resolving problem with this approach.

So I assured that a dependency `:domain` is properly resolved with gradle. It does work with all source files in `src/main/java` if they are .java files. However when using it in `src/main/kotlin` they do *not* resolve. This is true only for project module dependencies. External libraries do work in both folder structures. Placing my .kt files into `src/main/java` is not working either.

So this is the failing module's `gradle.build.kts` file:

```
group = "com.my.company"

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}
tasks.compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
tasks.compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    implementation(project(":domain"))
    implementation("org.json:json")
    implementation("commons-io:commons-io")
}
```

And this is the `build.gradle.kts` of the `:domain` module:

```
plugins {
    id("org.openrepose.gradle.plugins.jaxb") version "2.5.0"
}

group = "com.my.company"

tasks.checkstyleMain {
    exclude("**/gen/**")
}
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch")
    implementation("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-oxm")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3")
    implementation("org.json:json")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json")

    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-text")
    implementation("commons-io:commons-io")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-trace")

    implementation("javax.activation:activation")
    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api")
    implementation("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-junit")

    jaxb("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc")
    jaxb("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl")
    jaxb("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api")
    jaxb("javax.activation:activation")
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs("src/gen/java")
        }
    }
}

jaxb {
    bindingsDir = "src/main/resources/bindings"
    bindings = listOf("bindings.xjb")
    xsdDir = "src/main/resources/xsd"

    xjc {
        accessExternalSchema = "file"
        generateEpisodeFiles = false
        destinationDir = "src/gen/java"
    }
}

tasks.clean {
    delete("src/gen")
}

tasks.compileJava {
    dependsOn("xjc")
}
```

I have no idea why it is not working. May it be that this `jaxb` generator plugin stuff might cause some issues here? Just a guess.

**EDIT**: root `gradle.build.kts` : https://pastebin.com/nNTx1fKe

Comment: Can you please post the root project's build.gradle.kts

Comment: @kaushik added in question

Comment: `tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
  kotlinOptions {
   jvmTarget = "11"
  }
 }` I think this is the correct way of compiling kotlin. Try using this instead of `tasks.compileKotlin`

Comment: @kaushik What do you mean by "correct" format? Where do I need to use this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to apply Kotlin JVM plugin to the `:domain` module. Note that `kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"` in your root `gradle.build.kts` does not apply it to subprojects! You should have something like:

```
subprojects {
    apply<KotlinPlatformJvmPlugin>()

    tasks {
        withType<KotlinCompile> {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: he is using `plugins { kotlin("jvm") }` in the sub project mentioned also other projects are in Java I suppose

Comment: I don't see it. I see it's applied only to a root project.